# Why only Lyman alpha transition suffer Redshift in the epoch of Recombination in Cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, atomic-physics, cosmic-microwave-background, absorption, redshift

I was reading Baumann's book on cosmology (topic: Effective three level system). There it is said that in the epoch of recombination to form Hydrogen molecule two type of transition happens.
$$ 2S \to 1S$$
$$2P \to 1S$$
Then he described that only the photons emitted from the second transition will have a redshift due to the expansion of the universe. I don't understand why will be the case?,
Is is not possible for the photons emitted by $2S \to 1S$ transition to have redshift?
Can someone explain?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baumann is explaining how it is possible for Lyman alpha photons to avoid being reabsorbed by hydrogen atoms. The cosmic redshift moves their wavelengths away from the resonant peak.

The pairs of photons emitted by the forbidden 2s to 1s transition *are* redshifted, but this isn't relevant to the discussion, since they cannot be reabsorbed by hydrogen atoms in the 1s state. Baumann does *not* say that "only the photons emitted from the second transition will have a redshift", he just doesn't discuss it.

Comment: Can we talk about the time scale between the transition of photon emission and absorption for both transition?... The order of magnitude?

Comment: @KaziAbuRousan The 2p-1s transition is about 9 orders of magnitude faster than 2s-1s. The photon**s** created in a 2s-1s transition cannot be absorbed by ground state hydrogen.